# How are you supposed to get useful errors in Storybook?

Tags: storybook

When a component errors in storybook you only get the line number where it died in the main.iframe.bundle.js file. How can I get it to give me the line number in the original source file? Is there an option to have it generate & use some kind of sourcemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using typescript ? Are you using React or something else ?

On my storybook, I use React with Typescript. If I put an error like that:

```js
export function BookList (p: BookListProps) {
  // ...

  throw new Error('hey')

  return (
    //...
  );
}
```

I have this error embed in the document (is that what you meant ?):

[image: unintelligible error]

But I do have something useful in the console:

[image: Useful error]

When clicking on the link, it open the sources panel in chrome dev tools.

[image: source panel]